# Is it possible to call javascript function and access localStorage on "BOOT_COMPLETED" broadcast? (android)

Tags: android, reboot

I'm developing mobile web app. The app saves all data to html5 localStorage include alarm data. Since alarms be cleared after device reboot, I should re-register alarm after reboot.

I tried to find way about to access localStorage on onReceive of BroadcastReceiver, but I couldn't. Is there a way to call javascript function  on "BOOT_COMPLETED" broadcast?
If not, I think I should save data to SharedPreference.

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("DeviceBootReceiver", "DeviceBootReceiver.onReceive");

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // like this
            MainActivity.this.getWebViewInterface().reRegisterAllAlarm();
        }
    }
}

public class WebViewInterface {

    private Context mContext;
    private WebView mWebView;

    public WebViewInterface(Context context, WebView webView) {
        mContext = context;
        mWebView = webView;
    }

    public void reRegisterAllAlarm() {
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:reRegisterAllAlarm()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to accomplish and how long that is going to take. According [to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver), BroadcastReceivers should not run for more than 10 seconds. Because of that, running any javascript code or doing anything that might end up being unresponsive (http connections in general) is a bad idea.

On an other note, you cannot call any Javascript code without having a WebView using nothing but pure Android. There are libraries that allow you to do it without a WebView (such as [QuickJs](https://github.com/cashapp/quickjs-java)). You might want to have a look at those or see if you can create a WebView programmatically and using that instead. That feels like a hack more than a proper solution.

Your solution for storing the data and using it on a later time sounds like the best approach.

Comment: Thank you, alex! I didn't know such like 10 seconds rule. I might go with SharedPreference.